# Simple fit regression line in python

Tags: python, plot, regression

I have data from dataFrame plotted that looks like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHhqB.png)
now i need to add a regression line that fits to existing plot.

What is the simplest way to add regression line?

the code used is this:

```
df2 = myReport.loc[:, ['Quantity']]
print(df2)

plt.plot(df2, linestyle="", marker="." )
plt.axis([0,45,5023203,5938119])
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(df2.columns)
plt.ylabel ('Population')
plt.xlabel ('Timeline')

plt.show()
```

Using python version 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
X = np.arange(length(df2))
y = df2

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(X,y)

x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(),1001)
plt.plot(x, slope*x+intercept)
```

Comment: @dunkerboy if this does what you like, can you please accept the answer?